# What is the best way to deal with CSS style conflicts in React application which has dashboard and landing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm not really into styling, I'm a programmer, so maybe I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out how to deal with this problem:
I have a SPA on reactjs which has admin dashboard and a landing page. Depending on whether user is logged in or not, different module is rendered on the same domain and url. 
The index.html page is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's a session check in index.js, and if user is logged in Dashboard is rendered to the app div instead of Landing.
I didn't create dashboard style myself, I took a bootstrap template from the Internet with it's custom styles of course. I also have styles.scss file with the following contents:

```
@import "./custom";
@import "./font-awesome";
@import "./app/admin";
@import "./app/daterangepicker";
@import "./app/nprogress";
@import "./app/skin";
@import "./bootstrap";
```

This file is imported to index.js. 
The problem is that dashboard's custom styles conflict with my landing page's (which is also built with bootstrap) css styles.

So my first idea was to create 2 scss files with imports, one for dashboard and one for landing. But is there any way to attach different css files depending on what part of the application must be rendered and to be able to do it in a conditional statement without reloading the whole page in the browser?
Or maybe there are some better ideas to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally a hard problem to solve nicely after-the-fact. These css specificity and shadowing problems have not had nice solutions, in my experience, but you have some options.

You can give some top-level component for these two views an additional className based on the page and then scope your scss bundle, or the specific custom styles you need to take precedence, under that class. For example, say that app.scss has all the styles:

```
#app {
    // shared styles

    &.landing-page {
        // landing-page specific styles
        .bootstrap-component {
            color: blue;
        }
    }

    &.dashboard {
        // dashboard-specific styles
        .bootstrap-component {
            color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

A cause of this problem is simply that you have two different custom styles for similar components that use the same classes. As best you can, try to be consistent in the UI for a component so that the same component uses the same styles, with minor modifications applied through new classes. If that's not possible, maybe there is a different way to approach styling these components:

- The changes to Bootstrap styles shared between the two pages can be made as custom styles to that class but differences in the components' styles should be brought out instead, as modifiers to that component. Using the BEM class naming convention really helped me to do this better: [brief](http://getbem.com/naming/) | [more helpful](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/)

  - For example, if Bootstrap had a header component and both your dashboard and landing page wanted it to be green rather than blue, include that in your changes to bootstrap's styles. If the header, however, is smaller on the dashboard page and bigger on the landing page, those changes can be applied by new classes altogether.

If the server knows the authentication status beforehand (via some token - which it likely does), you can serve different html pages or different versions of the css. This kind of combines server-side rendering with some smart css minification. I don't think that's what you're looking for, but is possible depending on the scope of your project. I think that the point mentioned about about trying to isolate the shared and unqiue styles to a component is a better route, though.

Comment: The idea with top level component sounds very good to me :) I'll give it a try right now, thank you!

Comment: This worked like a charm :) Really good solution in my current setup. Thanks again